# How to make phone say something from commandline

Tags: root-access, command-line, loudspeaker

I want to send a command which makes the phone say something. Is there any way I can install such a command, or is there one that I don't know about? The phone is rooted so I have full access to it and can do whatever is needed

Comment: use automation app

Comment: Do you want to play pre-recorded audio files or are you talking about a text-to-speech system?

Comment: im talking about a tts (text-to-speech) system

Comment: Could you provide more detail, like what kind of input command and syntax you prefer to use? Something like `say <insert sentence here>`? Also, is the command run directly on the Android (using Terminal apps), or from PC/other sources?

Comment: i am using an ssh app which has SU permissions. the root permission works properly, so that's ok. I would like to use a basic "say <phrase here>" syntax.

Comment: i have connected to the ssh app via my MacBook air's terminal.

Comment: [Related using Termux](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-tts-speak)

Comment: this would work, but I am connected using an ssh app. If you know the path where the termux commands are stored, then this will be useful!

I also searched using ls -l -R | grep tts, and find -name tts, but nothing came up